# How to add addnotation for each point in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have that code:

```
for i, j in aa:
    plt.plot([xc[i], xc[j]], [yc[i], yc[j]], c='g', zorder=0)
plt.plot(xc[0], yc[0], c='r', marker='s')
plt.scatter(xc[1:], yc[1:],c='b')
```

And It generate this:

[image]

I need to add notation to each point. It shoud be it Y axix value. For example extreme right point is "1". It's possible to do that in simple way in this case? I found only help for totaly different cases and I can't implement it in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#dummy data
aa = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
xc = np.random.rand(10)
yc = np.random.rand(10)

for i, j in aa:
    plt.plot([xc[i], xc[j]], [yc[i], yc[j]], c='g', zorder=0)
    
plt.plot(xc[0], yc[0], c='r', marker='s')
plt.scatter(xc[1:], yc[1:],c='b')

# annotate each datapoint with its y-value, rounded to two decimals. 
for x,y in zip(xc, yc):
    plt.annotate('{:.2f}'.format(y), xy=[x,y])
```

Comment: Thank u for answer. I have 30 observations *so len of xc and yx = 30) and when I do it in this way (aa = (30).reshape(15,2) it's totaly destroy my plot. I mean, it's added notation properly but plot looks different now when it's shoudl by like in post. Can u explain me that "aa"?

Comment: Ok ! nvm , I got it. Thank u very much :) Now I understand that's your data is only random example.